# Wordpress stripping attributes even when explicitly allowed

Tags: wordpress

I've looked through every guide on allowing HTML tags and attributes to Wordpress posts, but it's still stripping the `allow` attribute from iframes. When echoing the `allowedposttags` global, it looks like `iframe[allow]` is set to `true`. TinyMCE's settings show that `extended_valid_elements` is set to allow all `*[*]`. The `POST` data to the Wordpress update endpoint is not stripped. I'd really appreciate any help in identifying the problem. Here's the plugin I put together based on a few guides:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:Allow Tags
 * Description: Allows one to add "invalid" and custom HTML elements to the Wordpress editor.
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: Sam Hill
 * with help from http://www.engfers.com/2008/10/16/how-to-allow-stripped-element-attributes-in-wordpress-tinymce-editor/ and many other sources
 */

class AllowTags {

  public static $instance = null;

  public static function get_instance() {
      if ( null == self::$instance ) {
          self::$instance = new self;
      }

      return self::$instance;
  }

  private function __construct() {
    add_filter('wp_kses_allowed_html', 'custom_wpkses_post_tags', 10, 2 );

    add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_allow_iframe');

    add_action('init', 'allow_iframe_attributes', 10, 2);
  }
}


AllowTags::get_instance();

function tinymce_allow_iframe($init) {
  $options = '*[*]';
  $init['valid_elements'] = $options;
  $init['extended_valid_elements'] = $options;
  $init['verify_html'] = false;
  return $init;
}

function custom_wpkses_post_tags($allowed, $context){
  if (is_array($context)) {
      return $allowed;
  }

  if ($context === 'post') {
      $allowed['iframe'] = array(
        'src'             => true,
        'height'          => true,
        'width'           => true,
        'frameborder'     => true,
        'allowfullscreen' => true,
        'allow'         => true
      );
  }
  return $allowed;
}

function allow_iframe_attributes( $string ) {

    global $allowedposttags;
    $allowedposttags['iframe'] = array(
        'allow'       => true,
        'align'       => true,
        'frameborder' => true,
        'height'      => true,
        'width'       => true,
        'sandbox'     => true,
        'seamless'    => true,
        'scrolling'   => true,
        'srcdoc'      => true,
        'src'         => true,
        'class'       => true,
        'id'          => true,
        'style'       => true,
        'border'      => true,
    );

    return $string;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried playing with the priority on the filters? I'm thinking a _higher_ priority (9999) might get these working, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried that, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Well, at this point I'd recommend firing up a debugger and stepping through the code to see why / how it's still stripping the allowed tag.